# Is there a such thing as on before hash change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application

I'm trying to implement some navigation resistance when a user tries to navigate away from a certain view in our single page app.  Basically I want to call something along the lines of a `confirm(msg)` *before* the hash changes.  I want it to behave similarly to `onbeforeunload`.

I found this question and tried out the suggested answer: 
[How can i execute code before hashchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25659960/how-can-i-execute-code-before-hashchange)

The problem with the one (unaccepted) answer to the above question is that it's using `$(window).on('hashchange',...)`, then when the hash changes it does a confirm *when you're already on the new view* and tries to navigate you back to the previous page.  This is not good UX, and on top of that if you have forms or a save in progress on that page, you lose all the state info from before you navigated away.

I tried changing his answer to use `$(window).before('hashchange',...)` but all that did was blow up in my face with a bizarre, seemingly unrelated error (see error text below).  I haven't seen anything anywhere on how to intercept a `hashchange` event before the hash actually changes.  Anybody have any suggestions?

---

Error message text:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined`

***Edit***
Ok so apparently I'm attempting to misuse `.before` so disregard that part.  I still need to intercept the `hashchange` event before it acts on the page

Comment: `.before()` is for inserting a new HTML element before another HTML element, it has nothing to do with event handling.

Comment: That would explain the explosion.  Do you know how to solve problem presented?

Comment: How are they navigating away?

Comment: Is this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208627/how-to-capture-browsers-back-forward-button-click-event-or-hash-change-event-in?lq=1

Comment: By navigating to other parts of the app, whether by using back/forward or clicking a link to go to another view

Comment: As mentioned in the question I linked to, you can use the History API to catch uses of the back/forward button.

Comment: If they click on links, you can use a click event listener to capture the click and do whatever you want.

Comment: But then don't I need to bind said click event listener to every link visible on the page?  That doesn't seem like a viable option

Comment: It's easy in jQuery: `$("a").click(function() { ... })`.

Comment: And if you only want to do it on certain links, give them a class and use `$("a.className").click(...)`.

Comment: I would recommend using a decent SPA library like AngularJS. I'm not familiar with any others, but I know that Angular provides ways to handle that sort of thing with an "on view change"-like event. If you want to get serious about building SPAs, you'll definitely want to check it (or another popular one) out. It will make your life much easier in the long run if you take the time to learn it.

Comment: We're using knockout and a variety of other libraries to accomplish the same thing as angular.  Don't ask me why

Comment: Hey, that's fair. Whatever works for you. I'm surprised that the feature you're after isn't built into knockoutjs, however.

Comment: If it is I haven't found it

Comment: Didn't go crazy reading it myself, but maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081671/how-do-you-observe-javascript-hashtables-in-knockout -- sorry, just realized that was for hash**tables**, not just `window.location.hash`. But in concept it might be similar to what you're trying to do... just make `window.location.hash` observable?

Comment: An observable is an object which contains a value, and which notifies subscribers whenever that value changes.  It doesn't watch another variable for changes.

Comment: What library are you using for your routing? (I'm not familiar with knockout, but doesn't look like it has a router?) Most routers should be able to provide a way to hook in to the routing flow.

Comment: You might be able to put together a hacky solution, by binding a listener to the hashchange event *before* your router's listener. Then you can optionally stop the event propagating.